# My template of creating folders from error when opening

Tags: php

I have a project to create automatic folders. but is giving error when opening in xampp.It seems that when running xampp, you have a problem. I am running a local server for this.I am new to php. Sorry for the bad indentation of the code. This is my code:

```
<?php 
require_once 'Util.php';
require_once 'NewFolderProjectItem.php';

class NewFolderProjectList extends NewFolderProjectItem {

    protected $projListPackege;
    protected $projList;
    protected $projListForExecution;

    // === PROJECT LIST
    public function getProjList(string $projID = null) {
        if ($projID) {
            return isset($this->projList[$projID])?$this->projList[$projID]:null;
        }
        if (!$projID) {
            return $this->projList;
        }
    }
    public function getProjListByID(string $projID) {
        return isset($this->projList[$projID])?$this->projList[$projID]:false;
    }
    public function newProjList(string $client, string $project_macro, string $project_lot, string $project_model, string $source = null, string $structure = null) {
        $this->setOk(true);

        if (!$this->getValidateList()) {
            $this->setOk(false);
            $this->setErr('NewFolderProjectList::newProjList::basic', 'Ainda não foi carregado os dados de validação de listas');
        }

        if (!$this->getNormalizeList()) {
            $this->setOk(false);
            $this->setErr('NewFolderProjectList::newProjList::basic', 'Ainda não foi carregado os dados de normalização de listas');
        }

        if ($this->getOk() && $this->getClient()) {
            $this->setOk(false);
            $this->setErr('NewFolderProjectList::newProjFolder::load', 'Já existe dados carregados');
        }

        if ($this->getOk()) {
            $this->setClient($client);
            $this->setProjMacro($project_macro);
            $this->setProjLot($project_lot);
            $this->setProjFolderModel($project_model);

            if ($source) {
                $this->setProjSource($source);
            }
            if ($structure) {
                $this->setProjStructure($structure);
            }
        }

        return $this->getOk();
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: The codes you posted are all functions --- and you need to create an object of the class and then use the function in order to trigger the action. Please post the codes which you have written to create the object and calling the function.